# Using DOMDocument.SelectSingleNode With XML Namespace Always Returning Null VBA

Tags: xml, vba, xml-parsing

I am new to using XML with VBA and I am trying to parse XML responses form the eBay API such as this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<GetSingleItemResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
<Timestamp>2016-07-04T06:24:28.969Z</Timestamp>
<Ack>Success</Ack>
<Build>E963_CORE_APILW_17911290_R1</Build>
<Version>963</Version>
<Item>
    <ItemID>232001428891</ItemID>
    <EndTime>2016-07-13T22:06:14.000Z</EndTime>
    <ViewItemURLForNaturalSearch>http://www.ebay.com/itm/WW2-Australian-P37-Entrenching-Tool-Cover-/232001428891</ViewItemURLForNaturalSearch>
    <ListingType>Chinese</ListingType>
    <Location>Pambula, New South Wales</Location>
</Item>
</GetSingleItemResponse>
```

I am using the following code to pull nodes out of the XML which seems to work for others but for me the `oDoc.SelectSingleNode` lines always return `Null`. I have tried removing the XML namespace manually and feeding that back into the objects, using XML v.4.0 objects, and have tried just about every combination of XPath I can think of. The VBA code I am using in its own module is:

```
Public Sub GeteBayItem()

'create the xml string
Dim itemXML As String

'Populate itemXML String with necessary values
 '.................

'the http connection
Dim httpCnct As XMLHTTP60
Set httpCnct = New XMLHTTP60

'using POST synchronous call
httpCnct.Open "POST", "http://open.api.ebay.com/shopping?", False

'set the headers
'.........

Dim xmlDoc As FreeThreadedDOMDocument60
Set xmlDoc = New FreeThreadedDOMDocument60

xmlDoc.async = False

xmlDoc.LoadXML itemXML

'Make the call
httpCnct.send xmlDoc

Dim oNode As IXMLDOMNode
Dim oNode1 As IXMLDOMNode
Dim oDoc As DOMDocument60

Set oDoc = httpCnct.responseXML

Call oDoc.SetProperty("SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:eBay='urn:ebay:eBLBaseComponents'")
'Debug.Print oDoc.XML
'Declaring a XML Doc

'Get the Item Number
Set oNode = oDoc.SelectSingleNode("/eBay:GetSingleItemResponse/eBay:Item/eBay:ItemID")
'Get the title
Set oNode1 = oDoc.SelectSingleNode("/eBay:GetSingleItemResponse/eBay:Item/eBay:Title")

'Set oNode = oDoc.SelectSingleNode(“ / GetItemResponse”)

MsgBox (oNode.Text)
MsgBox (oNode1.Text)

Set oNode = Nothing
Set oNode1 = Nothing
Set oDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

The code to pull the info from the eBay servers works just fine the only issues I am having are trying to isolate the response values from the XML but I included it in case the issue lies in there somewhere. Ultimately I am just trying to get the value of a node such as `ItemID = 232001428891`.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Where is the `eBay` namespace prefix in the XML document?

Comment: @Parfait Oops sorry I forgot to include it in the XML. It is now on the second line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple typo as the namespace declared in VBA does not align to XML, specifically you miss the *apis*:

```
<GetSingleItemResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
```

```vb
oDoc.SetProperty("SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:eBay='urn:ebay:eBLBaseComponents'")
```

Change accordingly:

```
oDoc.SetProperty("SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:eBay='urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents'")
```

Also, second `.SelectSingleNode()` does not point to existing path in posted XML, namely no `<Title>` element.

Comment: Thanks. Teaches me to copy someone else's code without looking really closely at it....

Answer (score -1):

Try xml linq.  I used Load(filename) but you can use Parse(string)

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Module Module1
    Const FILENAME As String = "c:\temp\test.xml"
    Sub Main()
        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(FILENAME)

        Dim timestamp As DateTime = CType(doc.Descendants("Timestamp").FirstOrDefault(), DateTime)
        Dim ack As String = CType(doc.Descendants("Ack").FirstOrDefault(), String)
        Dim build As String = CType(doc.Descendants("Build").FirstOrDefault(), String)
        Dim version As String = CType(doc.Descendants("Version").FirstOrDefault(), String)

        Dim itemID As String = CType(doc.Descendants("ItemID").FirstOrDefault(), String)
        Dim endTime As DateTime = CType(doc.Descendants("EndTime").FirstOrDefault(), DateTime)
        Dim viewItemURLForNaturalSearch As String = CType(doc.Descendants("ViewItemURLForNaturalSearch").FirstOrDefault(), String)
        Dim listingType As String = CType(doc.Descendants("ListingType").FirstOrDefault(), String)
        Dim location As String = CType(doc.Descendants("Location").FirstOrDefault(), String)

    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: I might be ignorant, but is this VBA? Sorry if I didn't make that clear in my question.

Comment: Sorry, it is VBnet.